# Execute Script After eth0 Is Assigned IP Address

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) and want to start a SystemD service after eth0 has been assigned an IP address. When this service starts up, it doesn't log the eth0 IP address so I suspect the After/Wants directive is not working correctly. Note that I cannot install another service (ie: systemd-networkd) on my machine.

How can I change my service to ensure my service starts after eth0 has been assigned an IP address and subnet?

```
[Unit]
Description=Get eth0 IP
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/sbin/ifconfig eth0"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Are you sure your device is named `eth0`.  I've got a Pi4B running stock 64-bit Debian/Raspian on a VM but haven't used it in awhile.  Persistent Naming may be enabled.